# Issue with Gatsby's addThirdPartySchema

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I am trying to create a custom source plugin and am trying to use the `addThirdPartySchema` method, I tried with this simple example below but receive this error:

```
Error: Cannot create as TypeComposer the following value: Test.
```

```js
import * as graphql from "graphql";
import { SourceNodesArgs } from "gatsby";

export const sourceNodes = function sourceNodes(args: SourceNodesArgs) {
  const { addThirdPartySchema } = args.actions;

  const schema = new graphql.GraphQLSchema({
    query: new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
      name: "Test",
      fields: {
        test: {
          type: graphql.GraphQLString,
          resolve: () => "hello",
        },
      },
    }),
  });

  addThirdPartySchema({
    schema,
  });
};
```

Comment: Your code looks fine, perhaps there's a mismatch in graphql versions. Could you confirm your graphql version in package.json is the same as the one comes with Gatsby (graphql@14.6.0)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following up to my comment, I run your code locally & can confirm the error is thrown with `graphql@^15`.

Downgrading to `graphql@14.6.0` (same as Gatsby's graphql version) fixed the issue.

Comment: It works for me too. Check Gatsby's graphql version by `npm list graphql` and then look for "graphql".